# What does "Eclipsed" mean in WinDbg?

Tags: windbg

In the "Locals" window of WinDbg there are several names with the value `<Eclipsed>`. In some cases the same name exists multiple times which one real value and the others are shown as `<Eclipsed>`.

What does that mean and why is this word used? Is it some kind of technical term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the memory is being used for something else as well within the function lifetime or that the name is not unique in this context.